# An error occurred while running subprocess cordova. Why?

Tags: javascript, android, cordova, ionic-framework

I make mobile game on JS, and i use Ionic for build Android app.
For adding to my project Android Platform i writed:

```
C:\TB>ionic cordova prepare android
```

But this back me:

```
? Platform android is not installed! Would you like to install it? Yes
> cordova.cmd platform add android --save

You have been opted out of telemetry. To change this, run: cordova telemetry on.
Using cordova-fetch for cordova-android@9.1.0
Adding android project...
Could not load API for android project C:\TB\node_modules\cordova-android
[ERROR] An error occurred while running subprocess cordova.

        cordova.cmd platform add android --save exited with exit code 1.

        Re-running this command with the --verbose flag may provide more information.
```

At my node_modules folder have subfolder cordova-android, why ionic?!
How can i fix this?
P.S. My android SDK at needed folder AppData\Local\Android\Sdk

Comment: ***"Re-running this command with the --verbose flag may provide more information."***

Answer (score 0):

Try running the following commands

`ionic cordova platform rm android`

`ionic cordova platform add android`

`ionic cordova build android`

Comment: i tiered, not work